# Maya - How to access grid colors through script commands?

Tags: python, maya, mel

So I've been looking around for quite some time for this but I've come up empty handed so far.

I'm wondering if there's any way to access Maya's grid colors through script commands. cmds.grid doesn't have any flags for it and I can't find any other command with relevant flags.

I've been looking through some of the openMaya classes as well but so far there's no luck there either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at what Maya internally does in *performGridOptions.mel*. The commands according to this file are:

```
cmds.displayColor("gridAxis" , q=True)
cmds.displayColor("gridHighlight" , q=True) 
cmds.displayColor("grid" , q=True)
```

This will give you the color index you can get the index with *M3dVies*'s *colorAtIndex* So for example retrieving the "grid" color would end up doing:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.OpenMayaUI as ui

index = cmds.displayColor("grid" , q=True) 
color = ui.M3dView().colorAtIndex(index)
print color.r, color.g,  color.b
```

Correspondingly you can set the color to any index with *displayColor*.